# AppleScript sum of a list

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get the sum from a list.

The list newTotal:

> {"30.00", "30.00"}

```
repeat with each from 1 to count of items of newTotal
    set myFinalTotal to myFinalTotal + each
end repeat
```

But the result is unexpected = 3

How should I do the math?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your original attempt:

```
set myList to {"30.00", "30.00"}
set myFinalTotal to 0

repeat with x in myList
    set myFinalTotal to myFinalTotal + x
end repeat

myFinalTotal
```

And for the joy of learning:

- Recursive:

  ```
  to sumItems from L as list
      if L = {} then return 0
      (L's first item) + (sumItems from the rest of L)
  end sumItems
  ```
- Iterative:

  ```
  to sumItems from L as list
      tell (a reference to last item of {0})
          repeat while L ≠ {}
              set the contents to it + (L's first item)
              set L to the rest of L
          end repeat

          return the contents
      end tell
   end sumItems
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Solved : 
I'm counting the list first then do my repeat statement

```
set sum to 0
set n to count newTotal

repeat with i from 1 to n
    set sum to sum + (item i of newTotal)
end repeat

return sum
```